# Make first keyword on regex appear first on results

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

```
MY NAME IS SALADIN ENDLINE
YOUR NAME IS JOANNE ENDWORD
```

and using this regex

```
/(YOUR|MY)(.*)(ENDLINE|ENDWORD)/isU
```

will match

```
[0] = array(
  0 =>  MY NAME IS SALADIN ENDLINE
  1 =>  MY
  2 =>   NAME IS SALADIN 
  3 =>  ENDLINE
)
[1] = array(
  0 =>  YOUR NAME IS JOANNE ENDWORD
  1 =>  YOUR
  2 =>   NAME IS JOANNE 
  3 =>  ENDWORD
)
```

then how to make the result of **NAME IS JOANE** is appear on first match (on array 0)?

i tried to put the **"YOUR"** as first keyword in **"(YOUR|MY)"** but still failing to make the results pop up to array 0

Thank you in advance

Comment: The results are always in the order they appear in the string, nothing in the regex will change this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think he wants `YOUR` always to be first, regardless of the order in the original string. `array_reverse()` will do the wrong thing if the input string was in the other order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `preg_match_all()`, the results are in the order that the matches are found in the string, not the order in the regular expression.

If you want a particular match first, you'll need to make two separate calls with different regular expressions. First search for `/(YOUR)(.*)(END(?:LINEWORD))/` then search for `/(MY)(.*)(END(?:LINEWORD))/`.

Or you could simply sort the result array with `usort()` so that the elements with `YOUR` are ahead of the ones with `MY`.

Comment: not gonna sort any results (too much setup), i wish the regex system capabble to sort by itself.. thankyou anyway

Comment: That would really complicate the regexp matching engine. Currently it's relatively simple, stepping through the string, testing whether there's a match starting at the current location, and adding it to the result set if so. Breaking the regexp up into different patterns, and searching for each of them, would be really complicated, especially when there are multiple alternative groups (you have to try each combination). It also means that `[abcde][abcde]` would have to be expanded to 25 combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP you can use the flags (PREG_PATTERN_ORDER and PREG_SET_ORDER) in preg_match_all() to order the resulting array. As the former is the default you seem to use a different programming language or you have used the latter one.

preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER):

```
[0] = array(
  0 =>  MY NAME IS SALADIN ENDLINE
  1 =>  YOUR NAME IS JOANNE ENDWORD
)
[1] =>  array(
  0 =>  MY
  1 =>  YOUR
)
[2] =>  array(
  0 =>   NAME IS SALADIN 
  1 =>   NAME IS JOANNE 
)
[3] =>  array(
  0 =>  ENDLINE
  1 =>  ENDWORD
)
```